# JQuery - Clicking and dragging divs on a screen WITHOUT draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently working on a small project, with draggable divs. The code I've created seems to not be working, and it causes JQuery to stop responding.

Is there a nice and easy way to do this without using *.draggable*?

```
var hold = false;
        //Drag Elements

        $('#example').mousedown(function(){
            hold = true;
        });

        $('#example').mouseup(function(){
            hold = false;
        });

        $(document).on('mousemove', function(e){
            $('#example').css({
                while(hold){
                    left:   e.pageX-50,
                    top:    e.pageY-50
                }
            });
        });
```

Thanks

Comment: Try this snippet: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/draggable-without-jquery-ui/

Comment: Javascript is single-threaded. While the `while` loop is running, no event handlers can run, so the `mouseup` handler will never set `hold = false`. So you're in an infinite loop.

Comment: Also, you can't put a `while` inside an object literal. An object literal has to be a sequence of `key: value`, and only the `value` part can be an expression. You should be getting a syntax error for what you wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Javascript is single-threaded, your `while` loop never exits, because the `mouseup` handler can't run while you're stuck in the `mousemove` handler.

Change `while` to `if`:

```
    $(document).on('mousemove', function(e){
        if (hold) {
            $('#example').css({
                left:   e.pageX-50,
                top:    e.pageY-50
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked a charm!